# How to show that an $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$-module is not free?

Tags: commutative-algebra

I do not know how to start with the following exercise:

> Let $R := \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. Show that the left $R$-module $M:=\big\langle 2, 1+\sqrt{-5} \big\rangle$ (so the $R$-module generated by $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$) is not free.

I do not see how I could prove this. (I know only the basic definition of a module.) All I recognise is that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is an ideal and two elements of an ideal in a commutative ring must be linearly dependent, but I do not know if this could help here. Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is generated by two elements so if it were free, it would be free of rank $1$ or $2$.

If it were free of rank $1$, it would be generated by a single element: you can then try to prove that no element of $R$ divides both $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$.

If it were free of rank $2$, then $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$ would have to be free generators (can you see why ?). You can then try to prove that this is not the case, that is, that $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$ are not linearly independent.

Comment: An ideal is a free module iff it is principal, so one can skip the last paragraph.

Comment: Could you please tell us where is this theorem stated and  proved?@user26857