# Why I should show that no element of $R$ divides both $2$ and $1 + \sqrt{-5}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, modules, ideals, free-modules

Here is the question I want to answer:

Let $R = \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $ I = (2, 1 + \sqrt{-5})$ be an ideal of $R$.

Show that $I$ is not a free $R-$module.

But here in this question [How to show that an $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$-module is not free?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3828256/how-to-show-that-an-mathbbz-sqrt-5-module-is-not-free) in its answer the author said that: to prove that it is free of rank 1, we should try to prove that no element of $R$ divides both $2$ and $1 + \sqrt{-5}.$ could anyone explain to me why this will prove that it is not free of rank $1$?

Here is the answer I am speaking about:

It is generated by two elements so if it were free, it would be free of rank $1$ or $2$.

If it were free of rank $1$, it would be generated by a single element: you can then try to prove that no element of $R$ divides both $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$.

If it were free of rank $2$, then $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$ would have to be free generators (can you see why ?). You can then try to prove that this is not the case, that is, that $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$ are not linearly independent.

**EDIT:**

I know that we are using the contrapositive of this statement for the proof:

$I$ is free $R$ module $\implies$ I is a principal ideal.

And I know that we are trying to show that $I$ is not principal.

Comment: "could anyone explain to me why this will prove that it is free of rank 1"?  No, the fact that no element of $R$ divides both $1+\sqrt{-5}$ and $2$ shows it is **not** free of rank 1.

Comment: @user10354138 I am sorry I will edit my question .... I meant to say not

Comment: My question here is different from the suggested duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $I$ were free of rank $1$ there would be an element $b \in I$ such that the $R$-linear map $\varphi: R \to I, x \mapsto xb$ would be an isomorphism. This would mean that there exist elements $r_1,r_2 \in R$ s.t. $r_1b=2$ and $r_2b=1+\sqrt{-5}$. If you are able to show that no $b$ in $R$ divides both elements this is a contradiction.

Edit. Let $b=\alpha+\beta \sqrt{-5}$, $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Z}$. It holds that $N(2)=4, N(b)=\alpha^2+5\beta^2$. Since the norm is multiplicative $N(b)$ has to divide $N(2)=4$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ and thus $N(b) \in \{1,2,4\}$. Note that in all of these cases $\beta$ has to be zero and that the norm can never be two. Assume that the norm is one, then $\alpha=1$ or $\alpha=-1$ and $\beta=0$. On the other hand $N(b)$ has to divide (in $\mathbb{Z}$) $N(1+\sqrt{-5})=6$. This means that $b=1$ or $b=-1$ are in fact the only options. This however implies that $I=R$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Can I use the norm function of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ to prove this also ? if so, how? is it easier?

Comment: why we are sure from the existence of this isomorphism ... is it because $I$ will generate the whole module in that case?

Comment: @hard I didn't calculate it yet so I can't say it for sure but I think one can use the norm here. As for your second question, it's one way to define free module of rank 1. What is the definition you are familiar with?

Comment: I = Rb this is our definition

Comment: @hard I edited my post which hopefully helps. Are you sure that this is your definition without further requirements like $R$ being an integral domain? I struggle to believe that is correct, but maybe I am just wrong.

Comment: Yeah  my definition does not require $R$ to be an integral domain unfortunately. May be I am also wrong.